# Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $xy = 0$. Then either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$

Tags: solution-verification, integers

Let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $xy = 0$. Then either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$ (or both).

**MY ATTEMPT (EDIT)**

Let us suppose that $x = (a,b)$ and $y = (c,d)$, where $a,b,c,d$ are natural numbers. We have that
\begin{align*}
xy = 0 \Longrightarrow (ac + bd, ad + bc) = (0,0) \Longrightarrow ac + bd = ad + bc \Longrightarrow (a = b)\vee(c = d)
\end{align*}

If $a = b$, $x = (a,a) = (0,0)$, then $x = 0$. If $c = d$, then $y = (c,c) = (0,0)$, and $y = 0$. If $a = b$ and $c = d$, then $x = y = 0$, as desired.

Any comments or contributions to my solution?

**EDIT**

The set of integers has been defined as the set of equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers according to the relation $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ iff $a + d = b + c$. In this context, the sum has been defined as $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a+c,b+d)$ and the product has been defined as $(a,b)\times(c,d) = (ac + bd,ad + bc)$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. What does it mean to let $x=(a,b)$? Perhaps you've used some construction of $\mathbb Z$ from $\mathbb N$, in that case you should make it clear.

Comment: For you, is $0$ a natural number?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: yes, it has been assumed that $0\in\textbf{N}$.

Comment: What does $x =(a,b)$ mean?  You said $x$ and $y$ were integers.  Why are you defining $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac+bd,ad+bc)$.  If $x,y$ are integers then $xy = xy$.  Period.  It seems you are assuming you are asking a different question about ordered pairs in $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ and assuming we know what you are talking about.  Are you actually asking a *different* question about defining $\mathbb Q$ as defined as a quotient space $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/(a,b)\sim(c,d)\iff ad=bc$?

Comment: I will edit my answer in order to present the context from which this problem comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is not correct. In this context, $0$ is the equivalence class of $(0,0)$, which is $\{(n,n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. So, what you should prove is that$$ac+bd=ad+bc\implies a=b\vee c=d.\tag1$$

---

**EDIT**

The new version of the proof is incomplete, since you did not prove $(1)$.

Suppose that $a>b$. Then $a=b+n$, for some $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$. So, $(1)$ becomes$$\require{cancel}\cancel{bc}+nc+\bcancel{bd}=\bcancel{bd}+nd+\cancel{bc},$$which means that $nc=nd$. Since $n\neq0$, $c=d$. If $a<b$, a similar argument shows that, again, $c=d$.

Comment: Dear @José Carlos Santos, thanks for the comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: I have been struggling to solve it for a while, but I did not succeed. Can you provide the full proof?

Comment: @BrickByBrick Done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. Just one more question: is there any other direct approach in order to find the relation $a = b$ or $c = d$? Once you know it, you can proceed as you did. However it does not seem natural to think of it as the unique solution possible. Once again, thanks.